# why i can't start odoo from docker image?

Tags: python, docker, odoo

How can I fix this error? I'm new to docker, I created an image of my project, when I launch `docker-compose up`, odoo will not display correctly!.

```
2020-04-13 11:34:34,640 1 INFO db werkzeug: - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - 

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:34:34,645 1 INFO db werkzeug: - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:34:34,659 1 INFO db werkzeug:  - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:34:34,684 1 INFO db werkzeug:  - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:34:34,688 1 INFO db werkzeug:  - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:34:34,694 1 INFO db werkzeug: - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:34:34,719 1 INFO db werkzeug: - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:34:34,738 1 INFO db werkzeug:  - - [13/Apr/2020 11:34:34] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:35:20,418 1 INFO db werkzeug:  - - [13/Apr/2020 11:35:20] "GET /web/database/manager HTTP/1.1" 200 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:35:21,476 1 INFO db werkzeug:  - - [13/Apr/2020 11:35:21] "GET /web/database/manager HTTP/1.1" 200 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:35:21,564 1 INFO db werkzeug: - - [13/Apr/2020 11:35:21] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:35:21,577 1 INFO db werkzeug: - - [13/Apr/2020 11:35:21] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

odoo_test | 2020-04-13 11:35:21,578 1 INFO db werkzeug:  - - [13/Apr/2020 11:35:21] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

docker compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  web:
    container_name: odoo_test
    #image : odoo:10.0
    build :
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5069:5069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data-test:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/project-addons
    networks:
        test_odoo:
  db:
    container_name: db_test
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo_20
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data-test:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    networks:
        test_odoo:
volumes:
  odoo-web-data-test:
  odoo-db-data-test:
networks:
    test_odoo:
```

Comment: Could you post your docker-compose file and the command you run?

Comment: looks like your `web` folder isn't configured properly.

Comment: @Guillaume i edited my question, first i did docker-compose build then docker-compose up

Comment: @PeterPrescott what web folder !! didn't catch you!

Comment: The errors are all 404 errors for pages that are in either `/web/static/` or `/web/database/`

Comment: Could you try to startup a official odoo instead  of your customizations? Follow this link https://github.com/camptocamp/docker-odoo-project/tree/master/example